# Changing the background image using UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiswitch

Hi im working on a simple App which is changing the background image using an `UISwitch`.

The problem is that on the device the pictures are in the original size. So I'm using 960 x 640 png's, should be fine but on device they are huge.

Thats what I was using.

```
- (IBAction)changedState:(UISwitch*)sender
{
    UISwitch *switchValue = (UISwitch*)sender;
    [self setTorchOn:[switchValue isOn]];

    if(switchValue.on)
    {
       // lights on
       self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"latarka_4_on.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
       // lights off
       self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"latarka_4_off.png"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Witaj na Stack Overflow, na stronie Q&A (pytania i odpowiedzi). Nie widzę pytania. / Welcome to Stack Overflow, a Q&A (questions and answers) site. I don't see the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have two sets of images.-

```
latarka_4_on.png
latarka_4_off.png
```

for sd resolution (480 x 320). And

```
latarka_4_on@2x.png
latarka_4_off@2x.png
```

for hd resolution (960 x 640)

Chances are that something is going wrong if you have pngs with no suffixes `@2x` but with retina resolution.

Comment: I thought the same in the beginning, I have included the @2x files in the recourses. But still the same thing is happening. Thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: Mmh and your .png images (without @2x) are 480x320?